# clickable image in textfield

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image in a text field and was wondering how to go about binding to that image so that I can know when the user clicks on the image Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tawrahim/RtV75/)

```
    First name: <input type="text" id="nameField" name="firstname" autocomplete="off">



  #nameField {
    background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tawrahim/testAssets/master/warn.png);
    background-position: 7px 7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left:30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
```

Comment: Because... that is not how you include an image in a text field.

Comment: I think this is hysterical, if that is not how you do it wont you correct it before you down vote. Now that you have down voted how do I get in your brain to figure out what you claim is right.

Comment: What is wrong what his approach anyway?

Comment: lol @AliGajani I wish @ Derek would answer that.

Comment: First of all, I was not the one who downvoted you. Second, if you include an image that way, there is no way of detecting a click except for calculating the coordinates which over-complicates the problem.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 no pun intended. If you dont mind sharing, how does one include an image in a textfield. Perhaps there is better way

Comment: @tawheed - Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/RtV75/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way you are including this image (as a background) the only way you will be able to effectively count clicks is to track clicks on the textbox itself.  The best solution would be to do something similar to this:

```
<div class="form-field">
    <input type="text" id="nameField" name="firstname" autocomplete="off">
    <img src="source/of/the/image.jpg" alt="Your image" class="input-icon" />
</div>

<style>
    .form-field { position: relative; }
    .form-field #nameField { padding: 2px 10px 2px 24px; line-height: 20px; } /* you should not target a single textbox with an id in css, using a class is less processing.. consider changing this to a class instead */
    .form-field .input-icon { position: absolute; max-height: 20px; max-width: 20px; left: 2px; top: 2px; z-index: 2; }
</style>
```

This will allow the image to be seperate from the input field, which will allow you to track individual clicks via JS.  If you need help with that part just ask and I will explain it.